# Java and JFreechart: get only modified entry from a DatasetChangeEvent

Tags: java, jfreechart, changelistener

I'm using a `DatasetChangeListener` to monitor the modification of some `XYSeriesCollection` because a change in one series must be reflected to other series of my application's charts.

```
public void datasetChanged(DatasetChangeEvent arg0) {
     XYSeriesCollection d = (XYSeriesCollection)arg0.getDataset();
     System.out.println(d.getGroup().getID());
}
```

I'm using `DatasetGroup` to store a string that uniquely identify the dataset.

Now the point is, I would like to know only the single entry of the dataset on which the changed occured, otherwise I am forced to iterate through all the dataset and inspect all datas. Is there any way to do that?

For example I would like to know that a changed occured for the series 1 in the collection, on the y value of the third element. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dataset` returned by [`getDataset()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DatasetChangeEvent.html#getDataset%28%29) is probably not useful in this context. Instead, look at the source of a [`SeriesChangeEvent`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/SeriesChangeEvent.html). You'll probably have to override one or more of the `add()` methods in a subclass of [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) to track the change details.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer. I think that's a bit complicated anyway, to realize that inside my application design.

Comment: In the end, considered that I'm using a mouse listener to modify the data, I decided to leave the duty of update the related dataset to a class accessible to the mouse listener itself, in order to avoid to iterate through all a XYSeries.

Answer (score 2):

I partially solved using SeriesChangeListener and adding a description String to each serie, but I still need to inspect all the values inside the serie.
It's a better solution than using a DatasetChangeListener (I don't need to inspect all values of all series in the dataset) but it's not perfect.

Comment: +1 This sounds like a significant improvement, without having to subclass `XYSeries`.